# Get selected dropdown value in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get selected dropdown value in vue.js in my method but i don't want it on change event.

```
 this.e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].dataset;
```

this is working on change event but i want to access it directly through class or name as i did with jQuery:

```
$('.dropdownclass').find(':selected').attr('data-id')
```

Comment: Are you sure you are working with vue?

Comment: [Did you look at the docs?](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Comment: @ulou: I'm working with vue, i want to know whether there is a way to get the data-attribute directly in the method,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how vue dropdown looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: [
          { value: 1, text: 'Please select an option' },
          { value: 2, text: 'This is First option' },
          { value: 3, text: 'Selected Option' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can also add `ref` attribute to your dropdown like this:

```
<b-form-select ref="myDropdown" :options="options"></b-form-select>
```

and then inside scripts something like this should work:

```
this.$refs.myDropdown.value
```

`$refs` is equivalent of `jquery` selector. `ref` is component scoped `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can u please let me know how to get selected index data-id because i want data id rather than value.

Comment: `this.$refs.myDropdown.dataId` should work, if not `console.log(this.$refs.myDropdown)` and then you should see all possible attributes of `myDropdown` in browser console. Also `this.$refs` might be an array if you will use it inside `v-for` with same `ref` name.